# RestKit and Core Data entity crash on objectManager getObject:self method

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm working on an iPhone app that is meant to run under iOs 6 and up. I'm encountering this issue under the iOs 7 64 bit simulator. I'm using xcode 5.0.2.

I'm using restKit 0.22.0 that I got from git but the exact same behavior has been encountered with v0.20.3

A very simple part of my iOs application keeps on throwing an error when the shared manager is making a getObject:self call.

All the mappings are correctly done and I know it because the first call works well and sets the Core Data Entity.

Yet if I try to refresh the screen it always ends with a exc_bad_access error at the line 454 of the RKResponseMapperOperation.m:

```
NSManagedObject *localObject = [self.managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error:&blockError];
```

I've checked the value of the self.managedObjectContext and the objectId and they are both set.

I would like to add that adding a new entity to the CoreData table works well as long as the Index is different from existing entities.

As I said the logic behind is quite simple and it goes like that:

Setting up the mapping in the appDelegate:

```
RKEntityMapping *analyticsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MainAnalytics" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
    [analyticsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"visits_today":@"dailyVisits",@"visits_this_month":@"monthlyVisits",@"percentNewVisits":@"newVisitors",@"pageviewsPerVisit":@"pagesVisit",@"avgTimeOnSite":@"visitDuration",@"date":@"date"}];
    analyticsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"date"];

    RKResponseDescriptor *analyticsResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:analyticsMapping
                                                                                              pathPattern:@"analytics.json"
                                                                                                  keyPath:nil
                                                                                              statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:analyticsResponseDescriptor];
```

getting the object inside the NSManagedObject :

```
[objectManager getObject:self path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"analytics.json"] parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(analyticsLoaded:)]) {
            [self.delegate analyticsLoaded:self];
        }
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)[error.userInfo valueForKey:@"AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey"];
        Site* ewSite = [Site sharedManager];
        switch (response.statusCode) {
            case 406:
                DLog(@"Already logged In user");
                break;
            case 401:
                [ewSite.user logout];
            case 403:
                break;
            case 404:
                DLog(@"error: %@", error);
            default:
                DLog(@"Uknown error: %@", error);
                break;
        }

    }];
```

Finally in Core Data the entity is correctly configured with the data field as Indexed... once again, on the first call it loads and stores the data correctly, adding new entity also works well and I can see the table getting new rows... yet when trying to update it crashes.

I'm quite confused here because I have another entity in the same application that use a very similar logic and it works like a charm...

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on here ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Is `self` saved into the context before you try to use it?

Comment: Yes it is, the exception arise when I get self from the context itself through an NSFetchedResultsController. If I create a new entity in Core Data I get no error. Yet this is a logic I'm using in another part of my app and there it works seamlessly.

Comment: What context is it created and saved in? Is this updating the persistent store?

Comment: Hi @Wain. When the error is being thrown it is not being created in a first place. It is being retrieved from the fetchedResultController which in turn gets the entities from the shared Manager used in my whole application. Finally, I don't manage the updates it is being managed by RestKit directly but I guess that yes the error is being cause by RestKit trying to update the entity in my store.

Comment: I'm guessing that the issue is that RestKit is trying to get an object for a managed object id that doesn't exist (either because it is temporary or because it is not in the context it is using). I can't think of another reason for the problem really. Unless the object was getting deleted from the context for some reason...

Comment: hmmm @wain your comment pushed me to investigate the addresses of elements in the execution (on debug mode) and here is what I'm getting.

My object:
self: 0xb1aa1b0
Inside which I have the NSManagedObject with objectID: 0x8e83e30

Inside the RKResponseMapperOperation
The local Object has an address I didn't spot in my entity
Yet the ObjectID is equal to the one I have in my entity>

Does it ring a bell ? How can I narrow this issue down as this is really driving me nuts and I wish to leave this behind me before starting this new year ;-)

Comment: @wain happy new Year!!

It's been a year now I'm having this issue :-p no really I still haven't found a solution for this problem. As I mentioned earlier the ObjectID is the same as the one of my NSManagedObject and I don't see any reason why the context would be different since i'm working with an ObjectManager that stores the context inside the AppDelegate once at the application launch...

Can you or anyone in here guide me on how to spot the bug ?

Thanks ahead,

Comment: Turn on trace logging for the mapping. It should tell you that the existing object is being found and updated. What does it say?

Comment: it says nothing but this:

2014-01-04 19:25:43.364 XXXXXX [10848:70b] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:148 GET 'http://{baseURL}/analytics.json':
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "User-Agent" = "XXXXX/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 7.0.3; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=(null)

I've turned all logging with this: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: Not sure you can use wildcards for the name. Use `RestKit/ObjectMapping`.

Comment: Wildcards are indeed supported. Yet I switched the name to ObjectMapping specifically and I still get the same output... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a sunday afternoon to spot the issue out I finally found the solution that had nothing to do with RestKit...

The issue if on how I was displaying the value of my Core Data Entity on my screens (Some of this value was unique so it was being feeding the text value of some labels... In the assignation of the value it seems a direct reference to the Core Data Entity was being kept and that was most probably causing a cross thread error...

I've changed the whole architecture of this specific part of my App to notice that when I wasn't displaying the data all refresh were working well.

Thanks Wain for your help. Hopefully this will help other people who are have very specific Screens.

Best,